# \Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a docker file to use node.js and nginx. When I run `docker -t build <my docker file name> .` I get the following error:

> Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.

Then in the docker file directory I created a folder name `web` and place my index.html and style.css file in it.

Question is: Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you provide more logs? specifically at what step is the build failing

Comment: @yamenk docker -t build <my docker file name> . is as far as I get

Comment: what are you naming the Dockerfile?

Comment: The problem is in the command used. The correct is `docker build -t ...` not `docker -t build ...`

Comment: @yamenk i name it by touch dockerFile

Comment: @tgogos that is not correct, when I do that it brings me to the help part of the docker command line

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command `docker -t build <my docker file name> .` is being misused. It should be:

```
docker build -t <image-name> -f dockerFile .
```

where `dockerFile` is the name you gave to the Dockerfile.

The `-t` option specifies the tag or name to give to the Docker image.

The `-f` must be used, if you name the Dockerfile something other than `Dockerfile`

The `.` specifies the docker build context.

Comment: Now I have a bunch of errors in my build. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, which wasn't solved by the previous answer. For me, the problem was that my dockerfile (named Dockerfile for convention) was accidentally saved as a .txt file instead of whatever extension docker has. It was hard do notice because my computer was set to not show file endings, and the file icon was still the whale in the docker icon. Creating a dockerfile instead of a txtfile solved the issue.